# Omitting braces after if-else statement gives an error

Tags: c

I came across this piece of code, written in C that gives an error: `error: expected expression before 'int'`.

```c
if (condition)
    int x = 5;
```

Could you please provide some insight as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Technically, from pure C syntax perspective, that construct is allowed. And e.g. MSVC [allows it](https://godbolt.org/z/d6q7oYMPE). The problem is that a variable declaration in that place makes no sense. You either need a "proper" non-declaration statement, or a brace-enclosed block statement.

Comment: @arye Both GCC and Clang give that error on the code. Which is wrong, and misleading.

Comment: Bottom-line, while C allows unguarded single-statement loops and conditionals, it is good programming practice to always guard them. It makes your code more readable and less susceptible to careless error.

Comment: Even if this worked, what would the point be? Consider `if (condition) { int x = 5; }` This does work, but is pointless, as nothing _happens within the branch_ and `x` is immediately out of scope.

Comment: For C11, the code is invalid.  In C11, there is a distinction between a *declaration* and a *statement*.  A block may contain either, but an `if` statement may only contain a statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “Technically, from pure C syntax perspective, that construct is allowed. And e.g. MSVC allows it.”: The C grammar requires a *statement* after an `if (expression)`, per C 2018 6.8.4 1. A *declaration* is not a *statement*, per 6.8 1. While the C standard permits extensions, a conforming implementation may not allow a *declaration* in place of a *statement* per 5.1.1.3 1. The MSVC behavior you report is not conforming.

Answer (score 4):

For an if statement with no brackets, it expects a *statement*, not a *declaration*, per the grammar in C 2018 6.8.4 1.

Just think about it, your declaration would be out of scope after it was declared.

Comment: The `if` statement expects a *statement*. If that statement is a brace-enclosed block statement, or any other statement, that doesn't matter. The error message is misleading.

Comment: “Just think about it, your declaration would be out of scope after it was declared” is not useful advice for reasoning because scope rules are not always taught before rules about `if` statements. This is particularly true of the details; early lessons about scope rules are typically limited to braces (block statements) and inside versus outside of functions. A student might expect the scope of `x` in `if (E) int x;` to be the containing `{ … }` statement. Even experienced programmers might not know that there are actually two scopes within `if (E) statement;` alone.